# How to make a list and its content const in c++?

Tags: c++

If I have a:

```
class myClass 
{
...
list<myObject*> objectList;
};
```

How can I write a `getObjectListPointer()` function that return a pointer to this `objectList` in a way, that itself and its content cannot be modified?

Which means, if I have

```
list<myObject*>* pointer = getObjectListPointer();
```

then `pointer` itself and pointer->at(i) for any `i` cannot be modified?
Like where should I put `const`?

---

Ok, my purpose is to able to modify `objectList` with in `myClass` but not other places, but I need to access the value of `objectList` and its content's value in other class, how should design the code?

Comment: const list<const myObject*> *const pointer = ...

Comment: @icando: That requires a copy of the list :-/

Comment: If you guys have an answer, could you just write getObjectListPointer() out?

Comment: You haven't made this easy for us :-)

Comment: How about giving access to `const_iterator`s?

Comment: @DeathTails Can you give a minimum example?

Comment: I realized after I posted my answer that it won't work due to the list containing pointers. The pointers will be constant, but not their data. So I've deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
struct myClass 
{
    std::list<const myObject*> getObjectListPointer() const
    {
        // Create a copy with const pointers
        return {std::begin(objectList), std::end(objectList)};
    }

    std::list<myObject*> objectList;
};
```

You may then do

```
myClass instance;
const auto& pointer = instance.getObjectListPointer();
// cannot modify list `objectList`, and all `myObject` would be `const`
```

Comment: Thanks, but just curious is there any way of not making a copy?

Comment: Creating a `const` instance but the down side of it is that non-const member functions can not be called.

Comment: @Nyaruko: By implementing a kind of `list_view<const myObject>`, but not trivial at all.

Comment: @Mahesh: `const instance` doesn't solve the constness of `myObject`.

Comment: @Jarod42, you mean implement a container? How should I do that to achieve the goal? Any hint?

Comment: @Nyaruko: Do you really need `list` ? `array_ptr_view` is simpler (change `list` to `vector`). It is not really a (owning) container, but a wrapper to provide the iterator needed. you may look at `span<T>` in [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) to have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
    std::list<float*> container;

    public:

        myClass(){
            float* f = new float;
            *f = 0.5f;
            container.push_back(f);
        }

        const std::list<const float*>* containerConst(){
            return (std::list<const float*>*)&container;
        }
};

int main(){
    myClass instance;
    std::cout << *instance.containerConst()->front() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs `0.5`.

Pointers can be freely cast to const and the compiler usually does so implicitly, but the template system can't handle that by itself. Casting isn't the nicest solution since it results in a new template instantiation, but if the resulting class has the same data layout it works.